# Appassure & Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to use Appassure with Azure Blob storage however tle Blob storage does not work with Appassure, and if I want to get ZRS replication only Blob is available.

Is there a way to configure it to work ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You probably need check with Dell to confirm if AppAssure supports Azure Blob Storage as backup destination or not.

You can also check Azure Backup service to see if it fit your replication requirements
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/backup/